# Assign const char * member of const argument to new value

Tags: c++, casting, constants

I am dealing with a third party library where I would like to modify a structure for the sake of simplicity in my code.

There is a third party struct

```
struct structure {
    const char *c;
    // ...
};
```

I have a function

```
void prep(const structure *s) {
    std::string str("hello");
    const char *t_c = s->c;
    s->c = str.c_str(); // structure::c is a const char *
    handle(s); // makes use of overriden c
    s->c = t_c; // Set back in case library tries to free/use memory later
}
```

How do I do the appropriate const casting here?

Comment: If you want to be able to modify the struct, don't pass it as `const`.

Comment: The function signature is given to me to override by the library, I don't control that.

Comment: You should take `s` as non-const or make a copy of `s`. If you choose to preform a `const_cast` you must be sure that `handle` and assignment to `s->c` can't throw and that the instance pointer to by `s` isn't actually `const`. It's strongly recommend to you avoid using `const_cast` if possible.

Comment: Then it isn't meant to be changed in this function and by doing so you a breaking the purpose of the function.

Comment: If you can't change the signature, you can do ```const_cast<structure*>(s)->c = str.c_str();```

Comment: On a different note, the pointer returned by `c_str()` will be invalidated pretty much immediately (definitely once the `std::string` is destroyed), so you will have a dangling pointer in there.

Comment: @You `x->c` is reset to it's previous value before the end of the function. There is only a dangling pointer in case of exception.

Comment: @You I reassign the ptr before the string is destroyed

Comment: Right, my bad...

Comment: Is it possible for you to make a local copy of 's'?

Comment: @Shane is there a reason you need to override the library's method instead of just making your own method for it?

Comment: @user888379 Unfortunately not, s contains member pointers to other structures that I cannot copy trivially.

Comment: @Eddge yes, I need to override the library's method because this is a callback. The structure comes in from the network as const and calls prep. I want to modify the structure directly for my overrides so that I can avoid complicated logic in parsing later down the line.

Comment: `const_cast<>` is only valid if original object is not const. Are you sure it is the case here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `handle` is declared as `void handle(const structure*);`.

The easiest solution is to copy `s`, modify the copy and then pass it to `handle`. Since `s` is `const` you know that there are no changes that could be made to the copy that would need to be propagated to the original `s`. You also eliminate the need to reset `s->c` to it's original value.

```
void prep(const structure *s) 
{
    structure mycopy(*s); // Make a copy of s
    std::string str("hello");
    mycopy.c = str.c_str(); // structure::c is a const char *
    handle(&mycopy); // makes use of overriden c
}
```

If you can't copy `structure`, consider modifying your function declaration by removing the `const` specifier for `s`. If you simply remove `const` you get the following function which compiles fine. Note that the resulting function is not exception safe. If `handle` throws an exception, you will fail to reset the `s->c` member to it's original value.

```
void prep(structure *s)
{
    std::string str("hello");
    const char *t_c = s->c;
    s->c = str.c_str(); // structure::c is a const char *
    handle(s); // makes use of overriden c
    s->c = t_c; // Set back in case library tries to free/use memory later
}
```

If all else fails you might be able to use [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) as a last resort. Be sure that `s` doesn't point to an instance that is actually `const` and be sure that no exception is thrown while `s` is not in it's original state. Being forced to use of `const_cast` may be an indicator of bad design decisions.

```
void prep(const structure *s) 
{
    std::string str("hello");
    const char *t_c = s->c;
    const_cast<structure*>(s)->c = str.c_str(); // structure::c is a const char *
    handle(s); // makes use of overriden c
    const_cast<structure*>(s)->c = t_c; // Set back in case library tries to free/use memory later
}
```

Comment: `try`/`catch`/`rethrow` solves the exception problem. Though I agree it's best to avoid entirely.

Comment: The const cast was necessary, as that is the function prototype of the callback, `void callback(const structure *s) { prep(s) } void prep(structure *s) {...}` does not compile

Comment: @shane Is `structure` not copyable?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no, `structure` is not copyable. I could write a free function to copy it memberwise, but i would rather not do that in case the definition were to change.